# Round to nearest multiple with offset in JS

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have a number I want to round to the nearest multiple of X **with an offset**. For example, how would I round a number to the nearest number that is 5 **more** than a multiple of 12 (ie 5, 17, 29...)?

Comment: Subtract 5 from the number ?

Comment: Given your emphasis on "with an offset", are you saying you have code to round to the nearest multiple _without_ an offset? If so, how about subtracting the offset before rounding to the multiple and then adding the offset back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case it'd look like this:

```
var input = 34;
var offset = 5;
var multiple = 12;
var result = (Math.round((input - offset) / multiple) * multiple) + offset;
```

This should find the nearest number to 34 which is 5 more than a multiple of 12 (29)

Comment: Knew it was something simple like this. Awesome!